# React Native drawer showing white screen in iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation-drawer

In react native drawer navigation showing white screen in iOS but working fine in android I have used below library version.

also there is no any error, i have used below versions.

`"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2", "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6", "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16", "apisauce": "^1.1.5", "i18n-js": "^3.9.2", "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0", "lodash": "^4.17.21", "moment": "^2.29.4", "prop-types": "15.7.2", "react": "18.1.0", "react-native": "^0.70.9", "react-native-animatable": "1.3.3", "react-native-attitude": "2.1.3", "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.1.1", "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.8", "react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.2", "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0", "react-native-config": "^1.4.5", "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5", "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0", "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0", "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0", "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.2.42", "react-native-google-fit": "^0.19.1", "react-native-iap": "^12.5.1", "react-native-keep-awake": "4.0.0", "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2", "react-native-link": "^4.1.0", "react-native-localize": "^2.2.2", "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1", "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.1.2", "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0", "react-native-reanimated": "^2.17.0", "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1", "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1", "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",`